# Can´t access BIOS to change boot device

Tags: windows-7, boot, multiple-monitors, bios

The monitor of my HP Pavilion is damaged. I have been using an external monitor to work.

Now I need to change the boot device order. However, the external monitor does not display the BIOS menu, beginning when Windows starts loading.

Is there any alternative to the BIOS menu to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For the HP Pavilion, when you boot up, keep hitting <kbd>F12</kbd> and you will be taken to the boot menu... It will occur after the BIOS but it will still occur before the Windows screen (obviously), so based upon your question I'm not certain if it will suffice or not...

[Source](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080711105252AAvjp8Q)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with one of my system. The issue came because I was using a monitor which had issues displaying during boot-up. Just because you don't see it doesn't mean it isn't there. I solved it by hitting <kbd>Del</kbd>, which was my boot menu listing.

Once I had done this I just wait for my monitor to respond. The system doesn't need a monitor to get into BIOS. Obviously you might have a different button to enter your boot order menu, which can include <kbd>F11</kbd>, <kbd>F8</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd> or some other combination of buttons.